# Unit test NavigationCmdletProvider's NewDrive method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm attempting to create a unit test for the `NewDrive` method for a class that implements the `NavigationCmdletProvider` abstract class:

```
[TestMethod()]
[DeploymentItem("PsFoo.dll")]
public void NewDriveTest()
{
    // arrange
    FooProvider_Accessor target = new FooProvider_Accessor();
    ProviderInfo providerInfo = ?;

    PSDriveInfo drive = new PSDriveInfo("FOO", providerInfo, "FOO:\\", null, null);
    PSDriveInfo actual;

    // act
    actual = target.NewDrive(drive);

    // assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual,typeof(FooDriveInfo));
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way to create the `ProviderInfo` instance, as it's a protected property of the FooProvider.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You could solve it using Reflection (untested):

```
// fetch the property "ProviderInfo" from the type "FooProvider".
PropertyInfo property =
    typeof(FooProvider).GetProperty("ProviderInfo", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

// fetch the property's value (of the object "target").
FooProvider providerInfo = (FooProvider)property.GetValue(target);
```

You may have to adapt the type information or property name, as I do not know how they are actually named inside your codebase.